# Create subdomain for each user that signs up

Tags: coldfusion, wildcard-subdomain, cfwheels

I am developing a project in Coldfusion with CFWheels MVC Framework with URL Rewriting enabled. It involves user registration and each user should be presented as `username.domain.com` instead of `www.domain.com/users/username`. Moreover once I am on `username.domain.com` all child pages should work as:

- username.domain.com/page1
- username.domain.com/page2
- username.domain.com/search?k=xyz
- ... etc

which I am unable to achieve.

I have updated my DNS settings of the particular domain so that `*.domain.com` all point to the same host. What am I still doing? I found [this configuration](https://github.com/cfmaniac/CF-SubDomains/blob/master/coldfusion-subdomains.cfm) , but I have not figured out how to implement it.

Comment: Setting up DNS is only the first step. You also need to set up your web server (Apache, IIS, nginx, etc.) to answer to requests from a wildcard subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is more of an extended comment than an answer

The code has a name of `coldfusion-subdomains.cfm` but it looks like something that would go into `application.cfc`. If you look at https://github.com/cfmaniac/CF-SubDomains , it states

> CF-Subdomains is a snippet of code (best used in your OnRequest Method of Application.cfc) to detect and include files from a subdirectory on your server and let it act like a subdomain.

So from here, I would go to the cfwheels documentation so see if it does anything special with `OnRequest()`

I don't see anything that wraps around `OnRequest()`, so maybe it can be used as is

You may also want to consider url re-writing instead

http://docs.cfwheels.org/docs/url-rewriting